# Using a class object in another class

Tags: c++, class, binary-search-tree, nodes

Node Class

As part of the tree implementation you should implement a Node class. Each node should contain a Customer object, pointers to left and right children and (optionally) the parent.

So, currently I have a customer class such that:

```
class Customer {
public:
    Customer(void);
    Customer(string,char,int);
};
```

In my node class how can I create a customer object while linking the two files?

Do I just include the following in my node header file?

```
#include "Customer.h"

class Node {
public:

    //Customer class
    class Customer {
    public:
        Customer(void);
        Customer(string,char,int);
    }

Node(void); //default constructor
Node(string,char,int); //Node constructor with customer details

Node* left;
Node* right;
Node* parent;

};
```

In the node.cpp file to pass in the values to the node:

```
//Constructor
Node::Node(string x, char y, int z) {

        lastName = x;       
        firstInitial = y;   
        balance = z;        
}
```

How do I pass the values of the customer object to the node construct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I just include the following in my node header file?

No. You just use an object of type `Customer` in `Node`.

```
#include "Customer.h"

class Node {
   public:

      Node(void); //default constructor
      Node(string,char,int); //Node constructor with customer details

      Node* left;
      Node* right;
      Node* parent;
      Customer customer;
};
```

Implement the constructors as:

```
Node::Node() : left(nullptr),
               right(nullptr),
               parent(nullptr),
               customer() {}

Node::Node(string x, char y, int z) : left(nullptr),
                                      right(nullptr),
                                      parent(nullptr),
                                      customer(x, y, z) {}
```

Comment: Sorry, I have a follow up question when I create the node, how would I then pass the values of the customer object into the node construct?

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful clarification!

Answer (score 1):

You simply include the header as you did and then declare a Customer object in your Node class (private / protected / public, as you wish). When you'll declare a Node object, the first thing that is constructed are the objects inside your class, and only then the class itself. So, if you would have a `cout`in both constructors with the class name, when you'll be declaring a Node object, you'll see:

Customer's constructor
Node's constructor

Also, if you want to specify how to construct the Customer object inside the Node constructor, you can use the list of initialization

```
class Node
{
public:
    Customer obj;
    Node(string,char,int);
}
```

and then define the Node constructor like this in your .cpp file:

```
Node :: Node(string x,char y,int z) : obj(x, y, z) {

}
```

this is just an example. You can use static values when initializing `obj` or you could also get more parameters for Node constructor and so on.